# MS Access Error No. 3058

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to enter new records in a table. Upon entering I get the error `Index or primary key cannot contain a null value.` It seems that the `resourceID` column is not set to `AutoNumber` - but I am not familiar enough with MS Access to determine whether or not that is the underlying issue. Here's some schema information, along with query.

Additionally, if I attempt to change `tblResourceStaffing`'s data type to `Auto Number` it says `You can't change the data type or field size of this field; it is part of one or more relationships`

What can I do here?

```
tblDBRPlusResources
    ResourceID -> PK, AI
    ResourceName -> Short Text

tblDBRPlusResourceStaffing
    ID -> PK, AI
    ResourceType -> Short Text
    PeoplePer -> Number
    LaborCost -> Currency

tblResourceStaffing
    ResourceID -> Pk, Number
    ResourceType -> Short Text
    PeoplePer -> Number
    LaborCost -> Currency


The Query: qryResourceStaffing
SELECT tblDBRPlusResources.ResourceID, tblDBRPlusResources.Name, tblResourceStaffing.ResourceType,
    tblResourceStaffing.PeoplePer, tblResourceStaffing.LaborCost
FROM tblResourceStaffing 
RIGHT JOIN tblDBRPlusResources ON tblResourceStaffing.ResourceID = tblDBRPlusResources.ResourceID;
```

Comment: The right answer is going to depend a lot on the business rules in place here. You could take off the relationship on your staffing table, change the data type, then put the relationship back in. But there may be a valid reason that the ID isn't an autoincremented number. If it is related to another table, it's likely that value has meaning and shouldn't be generated by the table, but is there to link to the table it is related to.

Comment: Yes - `tblDBRPlusResources` is the linked table. I think you're right here - it seems to be similar to MySQL's views. The problem is I have never used Access before. What would you do next?

Comment: Are you the originator of the database? If not, have you talked to the originator of it? There is no clear cut answer here. As I said, it is going to depend on the business rules that govern the data.

Comment: No, and the originator is no longer here. Otherwise I would not have been assigned this issue. Do you think refreshing the linked tables could possibly be a solution?

Comment: No, refreshing the link won't change anything. Are there other objects in the database besides tables? Often times data entry is done through forms that have code built into them that will fill in required data like that.

Comment: Yes, there are forms - I will update the post to show the structure. Let me know if you're looking for something specific, like VBA